# Transients in Capacitive Networks (The Charging Phase)

Tags: capacitor

Our class is dicussing capacitors during the charging phase, steady-state phase and discharge phase. There is a specific problem that I am concerned with. I believe the answer sheet is showing a error. The majority of us have the following answers for this specific problem. The error is the Answer belonging to the first time interval (1T). The other intervals (3T and 5T) were correct.

1T = 16.6465 V

3T = 19.9057 V

5T = 19.9973 V

Again this is for problem 19.C.. Could anyone else comment on what your getting as an answer and if i'm doing something wrong. The answer sheet is saying something different for the first time interval (1T). Again, I believe the answer sheet is showing an error in which I would like some support before I take it higher.

Attached is a photo of the problem and my work for the problem. Again 19.C. is the only part of this problem that I'm concerned with. The picture was fuzzy therefore I redrew the figure 10.94 in my proof of work as you'll see. I did this cause the value of the capacitor (5.6 micro F) is fuzzy.

[image: Problem 19.C.]

[image: My Work]

Comment: I think you just have a calculation error... 20*(1-1/e) = 12.642

Answer (score 2):

Your answers are wrong.  After 1, 3, and 5 time constants, the voltage is (assuming it started at 0, the problem didn't say but should have):

```
1:   12.64 V
3:   19.00 V
5:   19.87 V
```

I can see the error you are making, but I want you to think about this a bit.  What exactly is the meaning of the time constant?  How would it change the problem if the resistor were tripled to 300 Ω?  Does that effect the length of a time constant, the voltage after one time constant, neither, both?

Comment: Voltage across a resistor is equal to the applied voltage when 5 time constants have passed. If the applied voltage is increased then the acquired time to reach the steady state phase (5T) would be decrease I would think. I would expect if we were to increase the resistance then current would decrease along with voltage. If resistance was decreased then current would increase as well as the voltage across the capacitor.

Comment: However, during the charging phase current decreases and voltage increases to it's steady state phase which is equal to the applied voltage. This goes against OHMS law so I'm still confused.

Comment: @Shane: You are getting too deep into details and forgetting the bigger picture.  If a system has a time constant of 500 ms, then after 500 ms it will get 1 - e**-1 of the way to its final voltage.  Or put another way, it will have e**-1 left to go.  After 1 s, e**-2 left. After 3 seconds, e**-6 left.  Now what if the time constant were 1 s?  after 3 s it would have e**-3 left.  But note that your question is not in seconds but in *time constants*.  It doesn't matter how long a time constant is since the question is phrased in units of time constants.  Check the units.

Comment: Sir can you please help me with this question of mine :     https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/320852/115973