# Doubt on source free RL circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

Find \$i\$ and in the circuit . Let \$i(0)=12 A\$

[image]

Ans.\$12 e^{-2t}\$

I have worked out the problem(with a little mistake in it)...But I have a few doubts:

> Doubt:
>
> 1)Why is the constant equal to the initial current?
>
> 2)\$ i=-i_1=-12
>  e^{-2t}\$ . Bit in the answer \$ i \$ is positive. Where is the
>   mistake?

Applying KVL in loop 1
$$ 2\frac{di_1}{dt}+i_1+2(i_1-i_2)+2(i_1)=0$$
$$ 2\frac{di_1}{dt}+i_1 +2i_1-2i_2+2i_1=0$$
$$2\frac{di_1}{dt}+5i_1-2i_2=0 \tag1$$

Applying KVL in loop 2
$$ 6i_2-2i_1+(i_2-i_1)2=0 $$
$$2i_2=i_1$$
$$i_2=\frac{i_1}{2} \tag2$$

Putting \$i_2\$  in (1)

$$2\frac{di_1}{dt}+5i_1-2\frac{i_1}{2}=0$$
$$2\frac{di_1}{dt}+4i_1=0$$
$$\frac{di_1}{dt}+2i_1=0$$
$$\frac{di_1}{dt}=-2i_1$$
$$\int \frac{di_1}{i_1}=\int -2 dt$$
$$ln i_1=-2t+lnC$$
$$ln\frac{i_1}{C}=-2t$$
$$\frac{i_1}{C}=e^{-2t} \tag 3$$
$$i_1=i(0)e^{-2t}$$
$$i_1=12 e^{-2t}$$

Comment: Ah, I found the problem. Loop 2: It should be \$(i_2-i_1)2\$ in your first equation.

Comment: @KingDuken Sir, can you please help me with this question of mine: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/316246/stability-factors-of-a-voltage-divider-bias-circuit